# How to wait for a promise on an object to resolve before continuing async method

Tags: angular, asynchronous, jasmine

Is it possible, during Angular testing using the Jasmine framework, to wait on a property that is part of an object?

```
private async hasID(items: Items[]): Promise<boolean> {
    for (const item of items) {
        try {
            this.info = (await item.promise).json();
        } catch (err) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

`this.connectorInfo` in my test is returning `undefined` because I am not sure how to wait for this response to come back before continuing. I understand waiting for an `async` method to complete, but a property on an object seems different.

I have this object mocked as:

```
item = {
    promise: Promise.resolve({
        json: () => {
            return {
                ...
            };
        }
    }
};
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if i understood correctly your problem and how it relates to angular or jasmine but what about something like that:

```
private async hasID(items: Items[]): Promise<boolean> {
  let promises = [];
  let info = [];
  for (const item of items) {
    let promise = item.promise().then((data) => {
      info.push(data.json());
      return data;
    })
    promises.push(promise);
  }
  return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  // here is some logic that verifies this.info contents
    return false;
  });
}
```